# how can I read the content of the local reference table in JNI?

Tags: android, c, java-native-interface

I am getting a JNI error of the type:

```
JNI ERROR (app bug): local reference table overflow (max=512)
```

Now, I know the reason why it happens and how to solve it but I am having some trouble finding where (CheckJNI is activated and hasn't helped me much). In order to debug this I would like to print the content of the reference table, in particular it would be quite useful to get the same message I get when the app crashes:

```
JNI local reference table (0x6456b0e8) dump:
07-30 11:16:12.275: W/dalvikvm(14277):   Last 10 entries (of 512):
[...]
Summary:
[...]
```

I haven't found a way to solve this, and the only close solution I have seen ([Android JNI local reference table, dump current state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13283649/android-jni-local-reference-table-dump-current-state)) is useless now, as the class *VMDebug* is no longer in `dalvik.system`. Also, `android.os.Debug` (this class was referred in the old API of *VMDebug*) has no function to dump this table.

Is there a way to force the error message to appear? Or get something similar?

Comment: At least one of these is true: You need more local reference space or you're not freeing references when you can. How does knowing the last n references created help? Why not just free each reference after its last usage?

Comment: There's some references not being freed. But the code I'm working with is huge and it isn't mine, so freeing each reference would take me too much time. I need to know the reference table content because the error happens after a long period of activity. Knowing the content would allow me to know more easily when they are created, making it easier to find the source of the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have an answer.

Comment: That's alright, I'm afraid there might be no way of accessing the content of the table.

Comment: Dumping Reference Table: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13283649/android-jni-local-reference-table-dump-current-state

Comment: That is exactly the same link I added in the question, which I already indicate doesn't help.